# How can I replace a character and a word in a string with nothing?

Tags: java, string, replace

```
String mGateway = "null,"
String mGateway2 = ",nullnull"
String mGateway3 = ",,,,null,"
mGateway.replaceAll("[null,]","");
```

For example, I want to replace all commas (,) and all words "null" with nothing. The output of `System.out.println(mGateway)`, `System.out.println(mGateway2)` and `System.out.println(mGateway3)` should all be blank.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because it's a combination of a substring and a character.

Comment: `replace` doesn't use regex, `replaceAll` does. Also `[...]` in regex is *single* character set (or as others want to call it class). So `[null,]` represents `n` OR `u` OR `l` (second `l` is irrelevant) OR `,`. This means that `replaceAll("[null,]","")` for string like `null, not` will return ` ot`.

Comment: Also Strings are immutable, so `replace` doesn't change original string, it returns new one with replaced data. You want to store this result somewhere, even in reference which held original string like `original  = original.replace(foo, bar)`.

Comment: ``String mGateway = getStringInput("defaultGW", null).replaceAll(",","")``. So this would remove all commas from the string. But ``.replaceAll("[null,]","")`` wouldn't remove all nulls or commas regardless of their order... Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace an exact word, use `\\b` in `regex` as in:

```
mGateway.replaceAll("\\bnull\\b|," , "");
```

So this replace `null` or `,` with an empty String (thus `""`).

Answer (score 1):

First of all Strings are immutable. This means you can't change their state, so you can't change characters they hold. What `replace` method does is create new String with replaced characters based on the original String, so you need to store somewhere that returned String (even in the reference which held the original String).

Example:

```
String myText = "foo bar";

// this doesn't change string held by `myText`
myText.replace("foo", "x");

// this assigns new string with replaced characters to `res`
String res = myText.replace("foo", "x");
```

But you also have a second problem. Based on `[...]` syntax it looks like you want to use regex, but `replace` doesn't support it. What you want is `replaceAll`.

Finally in regex `[...]` represents *single* [characters set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), so `[null,]` represents set if single characters which are: `n` OR `u` OR `l` (second `l` is irrelevant) OR `,`. If you want to find words then you can't use `[...]`. You need the OR operator which is represented by `|` (like in many other languages).

So your code should look something like

```
String replaced = text.replaceAll("null|,", "");
```

I am also assuming that you don't have words like `nullable` in your `text` because the `null` part will be also removed from them. If you would want to avoid situation when you match part of another word, you can surround that word with [word boundaries `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). This represents places between alphabetic and non-alphabetic characters (it also includes start/end of text).

**So safer solution could look like**

```
String replaced = text.replaceAll("\\bnull\\b|,", "");
```

Comment: @Meghan Armes didn't see you ware trying to correct my post earlier  so my edit erased your suggestion (http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14371707). If you are willing to write it again feel free to do so I will accept it. If not let me know and I will edit this post myself based on your suggestions.

Comment: no worries -- it was nitpicky stuff that probably doesn't add much, ultimately. Your answer is great, no idea why it was downvoted. I upvoted it earlier. It's very detailed and helpful. Bookmarking for future reference. :)

Comment: @MeghanArmes No no, I like when people correct my mistakes. I know my English is not as good as I would like it to be, so any improvements/suggestions are very welcome :) Also no worries about down-vote. If down-voter can't point to anything wrong with this answer then simple rule "haters gonna hate" seems to explain it. There is also tactical down-voting but that bothers me even less.